# MVC Use DbContext in other controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dbcontext

I have two different controllers.

One is a came by `default ASP.NET MVC Core` :

```
public ManageController(
  UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
  SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
  IEmailSender emailSender,
  ILogger<ManageController> logger,
  UrlEncoder urlEncoder)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _logger = logger;
    _urlEncoder = urlEncoder;
}
```

and my own that I made with scaffolding:

```
public CarsController(CarsContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

.

**What I want to achieve:**
I'd like to use my CarsContext in one of ManageController's action method, but I don't know how could I instatiate, because CarsContext constructor looks like this:

```
public CarsContext(DbContextOptions<CarsContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}
```

. I don't know what could I add to constructor from a method in ManageController.

The task I'd like to achieve is to get cars from my CarsContext, to display those.

My another idea is to call the index method from my CarsController in method of ManageController, but also I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Can you make CarsController inherit ManageController?

Comment: There is a lot of paramters in ManageController's ctor, I don't really know where it gets, because if I check it references in VisualStudio there is no reference for it.

Comment: See : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97/sourcecode?fileId=147300&pathId=2049031892

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can inject CarsContext  to ManageController as you are injecting in CarsController and dependency injection framework will take care of rest

But do register CarsContext  in dependency injection framework.

Comment: Thanks your answer lead me to right solution. I have already registered my DbContext in dependency injection framework before, so I only needed to add the required class(CarsContext) to my constructor.